# String formatting not working with OS module in python

Tags: python, module, operating-system, string-formatting

I am currently working on a script that does some things to Windows directories and I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is the relevant excerpt of the code.

```
    import os
    user = os.environ['USERNAME']
    os.chdir("/users/%s/dekstop") % user
```

But when I do that, it gives the the following error,

```
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '/users/%s/desktop'
```

Is there a reason why the string formatting wouldn't be working?

Comment: `os.chdir("/users/%s/dekstop" % user)`

Comment: Note: this can't be the code that you ran.  Your `chdir` line misspells `dekstop`, but the error message has the right "desktop".  Please always copy-and-paste your code, so that people are looking at the right code..

Comment: @DSM It is code I ran, the problem is that I copied one line from my interpreter and the other from my script. Sorry about that!

Comment: @Ondaje: no worries here, because it was minor.  But it'd be very easy to have a misplaced comma or something, and if we don't see the code *corresponding to* the error message it will be very hard to help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `% users` should be within the parentheses:

`os.chdir("/users/%s/dekstop" % user)`

Comment: Oh wow... I'm dumb... Thanks a ton! You just saved me from hours of confusion.

Answer (score 0):

`os.chdir("/users/%s/dekstop")`   is a call to os.chdir without any formatting the % user would then works on the result of this which is not what you want to have happen.

You need to construct the string before passing it to the chdir function

e.g.

```
s = "/users/%s/desktop" % user
os.chdir( s )
```

But even more in this case as dealing with directories I would manipulate the path using the [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#module-os.path) functions e.g. `os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop')` although eneb ent you should look at the correct windows variables as not all setups will have user directories under /users